# How to write a shell script to create the network configuration file

Tags: bash, shell-script, networking

How can I create the below configuration file using shell script? The file should be created automatically using the script, using input from the user.

The path where the file is to be created is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3-range0`

The below details should be given by the user at the time of running the script the details are need to be get from the user and the file should be created.

```
IPADDR_START=23.82.132.2
IPADDR_END=23.82.132.60
CLONENUM_START=0
GATEWAY=23.82.132.62
PREFIX=26
```

Comment: How are you going to enforce this configuration on your network? Do you have a DHCP server running somewhere?

Comment: The files in the format of `ifcfg-e####` in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts in Fedora, RHEL, Alma Linux, Rocky Linux, CentOS, etc are for configuring a single network interface. They are not for assigning a range of IP addresses from which an interface can choose. If that's what you want, then you'll need to have a DHCP server with a pool of addresses of which the machine containing the interface is a member.

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. Please edit your question and add details. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
sudo cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
ls
```

Use your chosen text editor to create the script:

```
#!/bin/sh 

echo  Enter the filename to be created 
read filename 
touch $filename
echo Enter the Start range of the IPADDR
read startipaddress
echo IPADDR_START=$startipaddress >> $filename
echo Enter the End range of the IPADDR
read endipaddress
echo IPADDR_END=$endipaddress >> $filename
echo Enter the Gateway address 
read gateway
echo GATEWAY=$gateway >> $filename
echo Enter the Prefix value
read prefix
echo PREFIX=$prefix >> $filename
echo Enter the Cloneum value 
read cloneum 
echo CLONENUM_START=$clonenum >> $filename
echo “DELAY=0” >> $filename 
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/$filename 
systemctl restart network
```

Make the created file to be executable

`sudo chmod +x <filename>`

Then run the script:

`sudo ./<filename>`

Comment: A couple observations more to improve the answer: firstly, it won't execute unless made executable. Secondly, I don't believe this can be run in the directory you specified without `sudo`. You should clarify the answer that much.

Comment: Here's the full info on how to use the markdowns in questions/answers: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: You need the `dialog` command. https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807

Comment: yah corrected the answers. now it is perfect @Peregrino69